# Typing cursor shows where it shouldn't

Tags: firefox

I'm using the latest version of Mozilla Firefox, and somehow struck a hotkey of some sort without realizing it, and now whenever I left click anywhere, a blinking cursor appears as though I could type there. This happens when clicking any form of text, as well as some links or even images (The cursor appearing at one of the four corners), and even in some blank fields, the cursor appearing to one of the sides.

At first I thought it was a scant annoyance that would pass, but it has persisted for several days even after several restarts. I tried looking in Firefox's `about:config` but I haven't a clue what I should look for. Any idea what I did, or how I can fix this?

Comment: It was true, and I edited it to false and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to pnuts, I discovered this was due to `accessibility.browsewithcaret` being toggled to `true`. I'm not sure when I pressed F7 to turn this feature on, but changing it to `false` fixed the problem.

Comment: Which is most perplexing, as there is indeed a warning prompt, but I don't recall ever seeing it before.

Comment: You don't need to go to about:config to change this setting. It's in the options window as Advanced - General - Always use the cursor keys to navigate within pages